# Flask Socket-IO Emitting Across Google Cloud Run Container Instances

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, redis, flask-socketio, eventlet

I have been developing a web application that uses a flask web server, flask socket-io, and flask sessions. Previously I was deploying with via a docker image to Google Cloud Run. Google cloud run increases the number of active containers based on traffice, and to allow for session permeance, I am newly deploying to the web with gunicorn, redis, eventlet.

Working with redis and eventlet has raise a problem with emitting with flask socket-io however. The following message is logged when trying to emit:

```
Cannot publish to redis... giving up
```

This causes emitting to not work.

Upon searching the web, I believe my problem is because Redis is not set up properly to allow the Google Cloud Run containers to emit to with one another. I've been playing with the configuration for days, but cannot seem to figure it out. Does anyone know why this issue is arising?

Here is my docker file

```
FROM python:3.8.12
WORKDIR .
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  redis-server 
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
COPY . .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /tmp/requirements.txt
ENV PORT 8080
#EXPOSE $PORT
CMD exec gunicorn --worker-class eventlet --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 server:app
```

The set up within my server.py file

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()
# other imports
# ...
# Initiate session
Session(app)

# Initiate socket IO object
socketio = SocketIO(app, message_queue='redis://')
# I additionally tried socketio = SocketIO(app, message_queue='redis://0.0.0.0:6379')

# Example of how I emit within a path
@app.route('/path', methods=['GET'])
def functionThatEmits():
    # some stuff
    socketio.emit(someval, someval, namespace='/anamespace', broadcast=True)
    # more stuff

# How the app is run
if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=False) # For running on gcloud
```

The versions of redis, eventlet, flask-socketio, flask, and gunicorn are below.

```
eventlet==0.33.3
Flask==2.3.2
flask_session==0.5.0
Flask_SocketIO==5.1.1
redis==5.0.0 
gunicorn==21.2.0
```

Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up trying redis memorystore from google cloud and it seems to have solved my problem. For anyone who comes across this in the future follow along [here](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-cloud-run#sample_application) and use the following for the gunicorn command.

```
gunicorn --worker-class eventlet --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --timeout 0 server:app
```

Define socket IO like this:

```
socketio = SocketIO(app, message_queue=f'redis://{redis_host}:{redis_port}')
```

Lastly run the app like so:

```
socketio.run(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=False)
```

Leave the following the eventlet monkeypatch at the top of the server.py. Make sure you import redis in your server.py. See below:

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()

import redis
```

Also for those curious, in the question the gunicorn command was not correct see [here](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/discussions/2013#discussioncomment-7139172) for more on that.

Comment: Gunicorn in threaded mode will not scale well. You have 8 threads, so you will be able to have at most 7 websocket clients, leaving one of the threads open to handle your HTTP requests. Without using eventlet or gevent the scaling options that you have are very limited.

Comment: Got you. I have it behind cloud run which auto scales, but I will make the changes you suggested, make sure it works fine, and then update the code. Thanks, Miguel!

Comment: Worked as expected and the answer is updated, let me know if you see anything else that is off so I don't lead other people astray. Thanks again